# Is there a Google Sheets function to squeeze a range into one column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I wanted to find the built-in function for this to no avail so I had to write it in script:

```
function squeeze(range) {
  return [].concat(...range).filter(n => n)
}
```

This JS function flattens the 2D array `range` and returns it.

**Note** that it filters out empty cells with uneven columns.

Comment: So multiple columns into a single column? There should be questions like that on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not officially documented (yet), flatten() also exists as a built-in formula.
See [here for more info](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/flatten-function-in-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20the%20FLATTEN,separate%20rows%20in%20a%20column.).

[image: Example]

UPDATE: Since the end of 2020 the function is now documented. See [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) for more info.

Comment: Cool but not quite exactly the same: it leaves empty cells if the columns are uneven.
I've tried using FILTER with ISBLANK but it says the range needs to be a row or a column?

`=FILTER(FLATTEN(B2:L7); ISBLANK(B2:L7))`

Comment: For anyone who needs to debug `FILTER range must be a single row or a single column.`, the second argument (the condition) must be flattened also. So it's `=FILTER(FLATTEN(B2:L7); ISBLANK(FLATTEN(B2:L7)))`

Answer (score 5):

if `FLATTEN` gets removed by some evil google dude you can do:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C3),,9^9)),,9^9), " "))
```

[image]

```
E1:   =FLATTEN(A1:C3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JPV and based on his answer, I added `FILTER` to leave out empty cells:

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(B2:L7), FLATTEN(B2:L7)<>"")
```

Plus `TRANSPOSE`, I didn't specify this but I wanted multiple *columns* into one, not multiple *rows* into 1 column.

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(B2:L7)), FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(B2:L7))<>"")
```

Comment: You can also use `QUERY` to filter out empty cells: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158280/279532